# 9507 loader.go:222] Config not found: /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf - did you specify the right host or port?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a problem with kubernetes, when it will create namespace. And appears not found config. How to make the config in question??? and what does "did you specify the right host or port" mean?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwsDX.png)

I was hoping to find the config and maybe I could create a namespace. thank you

well i used linux debian for install docker and kubernetes. but error in kubernetes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok first I did kubernetes installation in "https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-linux/" . then i checked the version using "kubectl version -o json". After that I want to create a kubectl namespace aqua

Comment: You don't seem to have included any of your application source code or the actual error message in the question; can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  The filename in the question title suggests you're trying to install a cluster rather than write code, and those sorts of non-programming questions aren't really on topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DavidMaze i'm new sorry.... but well i used linux debian for install docker and kubernetes. but error in kubernetes.